# Get source roots in intellij plugin

Tags: intellij-plugin

I'm writing an intellij plugin, but I'm struggling to get any defined source roots. I'm using an action, but could use a component if that helps.

```
public class MyAction extends AnAction {
  public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
    // list the source roots in here.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured this out:

```
public class MyAction extends AnAction {
  public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
    ModuleManager manager = ModuleManager.getInstance(e.getProject());
    Module[] modules = manager.getModules();
    for (Module module : modules) {
      ModuleRootManager root = ModuleRootManager.getInstance(module);
      for (VirtualFile file : root.getSourceRoots()) {
        System.out.println(file);
      }
    }
  }
}
```